# Performance of external USB disk with ESXi5

Tags: windows-server-2003, vmware-esxi, hp-proliant, usb

I have a new HP DL120 G7 server with ESXi5. One VM is a Win2003 instalation and I have an external USB2.0 drive attached by USB Controller and USB Device.

I copy a 4GB file from  external USB to server disk.

In the VM that takes up to 10 minutes.

On a native Win2003 that takes aprox. 3 minutes.

I have no explaination for that diference:

- In any case the bottleneck is the USB connection, much slower than
  the disks (SAS, RAID1).
- If the USB connection on the VM would be USB1.1 and not USB2.0 it would take much
  more time.
- (The disk performance between server partitions on the VM is correct. -> see update)
- Could be that my native box is extremely fast and the VM is the normal case.
- ???

**Update**

As mentioned, i tried with **passthrough** and it is much better.

Comment: Is the USB drive connected via USB passthrough to the Windows VM?

Answer (score 0):

The best performance in this scenario would be achieved by passing the USB controller to the virtual machine (VT-D). Otherwise, you'll only get USB 1.1 speeds.